# Create credit card regex

Tags: regex

I want to create a credit card regex. but I want it to ignore spaces in this regex.

for that i created the format : `4444 4444 4444 4444` (for example, this is a credit card number and there is a space between it. It can read it.)

But what I want is `4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4` (To recognize even such a credit card number and read it without seeing the blanks.

```
(\D|)4[0-9]{3}(\ |\-|)[0-9]{4}(\ |\-|)[0-9]{4}(\ |\-|)[0-9]{4}\S+|(\D|$)
```

Comment: Why have you decided you need a regular expression to recognise digits in a string? Just iterate the string and pull out the digits, ignoring whitespace (and potentially hyphens) then check you have 16 digits and you're done

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression to match 16 digits that are optionally separated by whitespace or hyphens is easy!

```regex
/(?:(\d)[ -]?){15}(\d)/
```

#### ([live demo](https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=110625))

Comment: but this is not credit card number.
this regex also accepts a valid credit card, accepting a random 16-digit number that is not valid. I only want to accept the 16 digit credit card number

Comment: @virile ... huh?

Comment: I would like to accept the numbers of valid credit cards instead of accepting random numbers. Example: (visa: 4 5 4 3 5 1 2 6 4 2 3 1 2 4 7 3)

Comment: @virile How did you know my credit card number?! :O

Comment: I believe the best you coud do is to follow this example https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch04s19.html that will validate credit card issuers, but will not (obviously) be able to compute and validate the card checksum.

Comment: @virile Well, your question did not say that, and your original solution does not do that. Do you perhaps have an overly simplified view of [the possible digits in a credit card number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number#Issuer_identification_number_(IIN))? You really don't want to be using regexes for full validation.

Comment: all i want is to bypass spaces

Comment: it accepts all the numbers in your example. accept my credit card number format

Comment: @virile We're going in circles. I don't know what else to say that hasn't already been said. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Capture a digit, with a non-captured zero or more whitespaces, and repeat 16 times.

```
/\s*(\d(?:\s*)){16}\s*/
```

Comment: Unless you only want to match four digits, no...?